# Change Woocommerce Shop Category Columns to 4

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

My website shop is located at: [www.TattiniBoots.com/shop](http://www.TattiniBoots.com/shop)

I am attempting to change **only** the shop category columns to a 4 column layout.

I have tried to do this with CSS, but it ends up changing the layout for all other pages as well (And specific page-id css is not working for the main shop page)

I am hoping for a solution to accomplish this with a functions.php altering columns with an override for the main shop page only

Here is my archive-product.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.4.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

?>
<?php
 global $post; 
 global $woocommerce; 

$rev_slider = get_post_meta(woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ), '_horseclub_revs', true);                                
                if ($rev_slider != '' && function_exists('putRevSlider') ) : ?>
                <div class="rev_slide"><?php echo putRevSlider($rev_slider); ?></div>                               
                <?php  endif; ?>  

 <div id="content" class="container">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="main <?php echo horseclub_main_class(); ?> shop-wrap" role="main">
 
    <?php

        if ( have_posts() ) {

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
             *
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
     *
     * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}
    ?>
</div>
```

Here is my single-product.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single products
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
 ?>
 <div id="content" class="container">
        <div class="row">
       <div class="main <?php echo horseclub_main_class(); ?> shop-wrap" role="main">
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
         * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
    ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
    ?>






</div>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post with related code (the code from your `archive-product.php` file), we can't really do anything with what your are giving us right now

Comment: Yes! I just added this for you, thank you for letting me know that

Comment: Hey again, sadly you need to work a bit more, the file we're looking for isn't here, can you go and grab the `content-product.php` and edit your post once more (leave the archive-product.php code in your post i might use it later on)

Comment: Hmm, there is no content-product.php however there is single-product.php. I have added this for you as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `loop_shop_column` filter:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns', 999);
function loop_columns() {
    return is_product_category() ? 4 : 3; 
}
```

The above example returns 4 columns for your category pages and 3 columns for your main shop page (or any other product overview page)

Simply add this to the functions.php of your child theme or via a plugin like Code Snippets.

Comment: I have added this to my functions.php. Shop still appears as follows: https://www.tattiniboots.com/shop/

Comment: Are you sure the filter is being called?

Comment: Of course! I can attach the functions.php if you would like as well

Comment: The Shop <UL> Source vividly declares 3 columns :/ - https://i.imgur.com/SGnMWdv.png

Comment: Is that your main shop page? Or category page?

Comment: Both. My main Shop page displays the categories. Only thing that code changed was the layout inside the categories. Now that is a 2 column view: https://www.tattiniboots.com/product-category/tall-boots/

Comment: The above answer is the correct one if your theme is setup right. You can see this question is closed because a similar question already has the same answer. You could check if your theme make correct use of the `loop_shop_columns` filter.

Comment: I need the MAIN shop page to be 4 columns.. this page: www.TattiniBoots.com/shop

Comment: With the internal categories keeping their 3 column look